# Serialize custom object list in a Response with kotlinx

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, serialization

I have the next json as response:

```
 {"id":1581,"title":"hhhh","tags":[],"iconUrl":"images/b94cdcde-9c6c-4ea1-9c22-47b4c1750cce","valoration":0,"postList":[{"id":41,"x":0.58,"y":0.3,"rotation":338,"resourceUrl":"images/ba4202c2-845f-4b70-8167-5ef4ffb347bf","valoration":0}]}
```

And I have declared the response at my project as:

```
@Serializable
data class BoardResponse(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerialName("title")
    val title: String,
    @SerialName("tags")
    val tags: List<String>,
    @SerialName("iconUrl")
    val iconUrl: String,
    @SerialName("valoration")
    val valoration: Float,
    @SerialName("postList")
    val posts: List<PostResponse>
)
```

The problem is that I'm getting allways a null in the "posts" value.

This is the PostResponse:

```
@Serializable
data class PostResponse(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerialName("x")
    val x: Float,
    @SerialName("y")
    val y: Float,
    @SerialName("rotation")
    val rotation: Int,
    @SerialName("resourceUrl")
    val resourceUrl: String,
    @SerialName("valoration")
    val valoration: Float
)
```

Can I do what I'm trying to do in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. With the exact same declarations as yours, and with the example JSON you provided, the following test passes (you get non-null `posts`):

```kotlin
@Test
fun test() {
    val json = """{"id":1581,"title":"hhhh","tags":[],"iconUrl":"images/b94cdcde-9c6c-4ea1-9c22-47b4c1750cce","valoration":0,"postList":[{"id":41,"x":0.58,"y":0.3,"rotation":338,"resourceUrl":"images/ba4202c2-845f-4b70-8167-5ef4ffb347bf","valoration":0}]}"""
    val resp = Json.decodeFromString<BoardResponse>(json)
    assertEquals(1, resp.posts.size)
}
```

I believe something must be wrong in how you setup Kotlinx Serialization as deserialization library. Please update your question with more details about how you use the library to deserialize this JSON, or open another question.

Comment: I downgraded the kotlin version to "1.4.32", it fixed the problem, yes, It could be a problem with the libraries.

Comment: The test above passes with Kotlin 1.5.10, and Kotlinx Serialization 1.2.0

Answer (score -1):

data class PostResponse(
val id: Int,
val x: Float,
val y: Float,
val rotation: Int,
val resourceUrl: String,
val valoration: Float
) : Serializable

**Note: All variables names must be same as your response parameters(key)**

Comment: This is what the OP said in his own answer (no need to repost), and is also still factually incorrect. Using `@SerialName` allows to decouple the Kotlin property name from their JSON name in serialized form.

Answer (score -2):

Forget it, the only problem was the name of the val:

val posts: List

Just changed that to postList and it worked. No idea that the val name could be linked to the json name.

Comment: The `@SerialName` annotation is supposed to override this behaviour, though. Are you sure that was the problem? It might be that you're not using the Kotlinx Serialization library to deserialize that JSON, but maybe you're using something else (like Jackson) behind the scenes without knowing it.

Comment: Yes sorry I must be confused when I did this answer! I checked this morning, I also downgraded the kotlin version to "1.4.32". But I cant understand exactly why the version "1.5.x" wasnt working